# IE10 - How to display json formatted in response body of network developer tools

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, internet-explorer-10

When monitering network traffic (ajax traffic) in developer tools of IE10. I tried to check the request body. Though it showed me the json text inside the response body. It is not formatted in any way, just one straight line. How can I show it in a formatted view?

Thanks

Comment: That's what I want as well, unfortunately the company doesn't offer that :(

Comment: @artistoex there are tons of financial institutions that cannot use any other web browser other than IE.This is something a few programmers have to deal with

Comment: @ggderas This may be true, but for most debugging purposes I'd prefer anything but IE

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer, but I tend to keep a http://jsbeautifier.org/ window open for such things.  Get cursor in field, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, go to beautifier window, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, click "Beautify Javascript or Html"... the whole keysequence + mouse movements is not immediate, but it is pretty quick.  You could also use Fiddler2 and add a JSON formatter if your company would allow installation of that.

Comment: I don't think this would help since IE doesn't do JSON format, rather it has % characters and numbers, I don't know, a weird and almost unreadable thing

Comment: @ggderas I'm really not sure what you are talking about.  You could use the IE developer tools and see AJAX/JSON  responses back 5 years ago when this answer was written, and you can do similarly now.  IE, as far as I know, has handled reading JSON just fine for quite a while.  IE developer tools has a pretty printer now, which makes this question and answer irrelevant. You seem to be talking about URI encoding for some reason.  That would take, say, the `"` character and replace it with `%22`.

Comment: I'm aware of response body on JSON format on IE, but regarding request body, can't seem to get a JSON fine format. It's always unreadable, perhaps I'm talking about URI encoding, but on Chrome all data looks just fine

Comment: I've googled this and yes, you're right. This actually helped me!

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click in the Response Body tab there is an option to word wrap. That makes it possible to see the entire line. However, it still does not format it in a nice JSON format.

(I know this question is almost a year old. But I found this when I had this same question. So thought I would answer with what I found.)